# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adaptor error oracle client 19

Tags: oracle

I have problem  connect  to  databases  ORACLE. I can't connect through SQL PLUS [image]

I surfed the whole internet everyone writes about oracleSERVICE ORACLESERVICEORCL services but I don't have them installed on WINDOWS SERWER 2016.

Please
Help Solutions problem

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894558/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adaptor-error

Comment: No I dont have Oracle ServiceORCL because I have oracle client 19

Comment: I*m Sorry, Because I first asked questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Which database are you connecting to? Where is it installed (on which computer)? Is that computer (also known as a "database server") accessible to you over the network (unless database is installed on your own PC)?

Comment: If you had used copy and paste from your command line session - instead of taking a picture of your screen with your smart-phone, we probably could better tell exactly what you did. That said, your error is almost always due to trying to make a 'local' connection to a database that does not exist on the local machine.  I seriously doubt you searched the 'entire' internet, but the references to 'orcl' are an example.  You say you installed 'oracle client', but where is your database, and what was the _exact_ sql command you used to try to connect?